# Выравнивание отдельного элемента по горизонтали (FlexBox)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

## Имеется:

Имеется тестовое меню реализованное на флексах, необходимо определенный элемент меню прижать к левому или правому краю.

```css
.nav
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: bisque;

  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  // ie fix
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav__item
{
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 1</li>
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 2</li>
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 3</li>
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 4</li>
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

## Что получилось:

Выбрал 3й пункт в качестве подопытного, сделал его крайним через `order` и далее прижал его к правому краю через `margin-left: auto;`.

Везде работает, но правильно-ли решать таким способом задачу, может есть более грамотный способ?

```css
.nav
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: bisque;

  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
  // ie fix
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav__item
{
  background: orange;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav__item:nth-child(3)
{
  order: 999;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 1</li>
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 2</li>
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 3</li>
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 4</li>
  <li class="nav__item">Пункт 5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Если они не будут динамически менятся, то я бы просто обернул пункты которые с одной стороны в `div` и сделал `space-between`. Если же предполагается какой то интерактив, то да `order` хорошее решение.

Comment: Хотел найти решение в `flexbox` как в `cssgrid`, чтобы из `коробки` можно было менять положение элементов без дополнительных `костылей`. К сожалению, видимо такого нет...